# Can't read from a file in haskell

Tags: file, haskell, io

I have been trying to use the readFile syntax in haskell but when I try to do it i get an error which I don't know how to fix.

My code:

```
import System.Environment

maze_path = "maze2.txt"

get_maze :: String -> IO [String]
get_maze file = 
    do 
        x <- readFile file
        return (read x)
```

The error:

```
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

This error is gotten from executing the function 'get_maze' with the 'mape_path' string.

I am just trying to get the full contents of the file into a regular string format, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error is in `read` not `readFile`. Your file contents is not formatted as `[String]`. If you want to read a list of lines, try `lines x` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
x <- readFile file
```

works as you assume and assigns the contents of the given file to the variable `x` as a `String`. The error is thrown by the `read` function.

The `read` function converts a `String` to a given output type. In your case, given the type `get_maze :: String -> IO [String]`, Haskell determines that `read` must have the type `String -> [String]`. As a result, the text file is expected to contain a formatted array of strings, essentially what you would get by writing e.g. `show ["Hello", "World"]` (`["Hello","World"]`).

The file does not seem to be formatted in that way. If `read` can't parse an input, it will throw the error that you got above. There are more robust ways to parse stuff in Haskell, but I could imagine that your file is simply not formatted in that way and that you want to use a different function.

If you just want to get a list of lines, for example, there is the `lines :: String -> [String]` [function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lines) in Haskell, which splits a string into a list of lines.